# Windows Phone 7 JSON InvalidCastException

Tags: json, windows-phone-7, deserialization

JSON Code:

```
{"date":"2011.12.10, szombat ","route":"Jászfényszaru - MISKOLC*","timetable":[{"class_name":" 2. ","cost1st":"","destinationtime":"07:50","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"2","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"05:37","starttime":"05:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5729 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"05:47","starttime":"05:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"05:56","starttime":"05:54","platform":"4","traininfo":"5500 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Eger)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"06:42","starttime":"06:46","platform":"3","traininfo":"","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"07:01","starttime":"07:00","platform":"1","traininfo":"5062 személy ( - Miskolc-Tiszai)","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"07:48","starttime":"07:50","platform":"8","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:13","starttime":"05:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 2. ","ticket":null,"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.020 Ft ","destinationtime":"08:21","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"1","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"05:37","starttime":"05:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5729 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"05:47","starttime":"05:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"06:58","starttime":"06:56","platform":"4","traininfo":"5200 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Sátoraljaújhely)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"08:23","starttime":"08:21","platform":"8","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:44","starttime":"05:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":null,"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.300 Ft ","destinationtime":"09:31","reservation":"","distance":"126 km","change":"2","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"07:36","starttime":"07:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5749 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"07:47","starttime":"07:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"07:56","starttime":"07:54","platform":"4","traininfo":"5510 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Eger)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"08:43","starttime":"08:45","platform":"6","traininfo":"","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"08:54","starttime":"08:53","platform":"3","traininfo":"657 DÁLIA IC (Budapest-Keleti - Budapest-Nyugati)","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"09:28","starttime":"09:31","platform":"9","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"1:54","starttime":"07:37","cost2nd":"3.020 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":null,"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.020 Ft ","destinationtime":"10:21","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"1","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"07:36","starttime":"07:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5749 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"07:47","starttime":"07:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"09:00","starttime":"08:56","platform":"4","traininfo":"520 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Sátoraljaújhely)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"10:24","starttime":"10:21","platform":"8","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:44","starttime":"07:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":null,"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.300 Ft ","destinationtime":"11:31","reservation":"","distance":"126 km","change":"2","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"09:39","starttime":"09:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5727 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"09:51","starttime":"09:47","platform":"2","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"09:58","starttime":"09:54","platform":"4","traininfo":"5502 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Eger)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"10:47","starttime":"10:45","platform":"6","traininfo":"","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"10:55","starttime":"10:53","platform":"3","traininfo":"564 JÁZMIN IC (Budapest-Keleti - Budapest-Nyugati)","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"11:31","starttime":"11:31","platform":"9","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"1:54","starttime":"09:37","cost2nd":"3.020 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":null,"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.020 Ft ","destinationtime":"12:21","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"1","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"09:39","starttime":"09:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5727 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"09:51","starttime":"09:47","platform":"2","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"10:59","starttime":"10:56","platform":"4","traininfo":"522 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Sátoraljaújhely)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"12:23","starttime":"12:21","platform":"8","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:44","starttime":"09:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":null,"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.300 Ft ","destinationtime":"13:31","reservation":"","distance":"126 km","change":"2","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"11:37","starttime":"11:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5747 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"11:48","starttime":"11:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"12:02","starttime":"11:54","platform":"4","traininfo":"5512 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Eger)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"12:45","starttime":"12:45","platform":"6","traininfo":"","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"12:54","starttime":"12:53","platform":"3","traininfo":"655 KAMILLA IC (Budapest-Keleti - Budapest-Nyugati)","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"13:29","starttime":"13:31","platform":"9","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"1:54","starttime":"11:37","cost2nd":"3.020 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":null,"start":""},{"class_name":" 2. ","cost1st":"","destinationtime":"13:50","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"2","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"11:37","starttime":"11:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5747 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"11:48","starttime":"11:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"12:02","starttime":"11:54","platform":"4","traininfo":"5512 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Eger)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"12:45","starttime":"12:45","platform":"6","traininfo":"","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"13:01","starttime":"13:00","platform":"1","traininfo":"5334 személy ( - Hidasnémeti)","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"13:51","starttime":"13:50","platform":"7","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:13","starttime":"11:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 2. ","ticket":null,"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.020 Ft ","destinationtime":"14:21","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"1","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"11:37","starttime":"11:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5747 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"11:48","starttime":"11:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"12:57","starttime":"12:56","platform":"4","traininfo":"524 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Sátoraljaújhely)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"14:22","starttime":"14:21","platform":"8","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:44","starttime":"11:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":null,"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.300 Ft ","destinationtime":"15:31","reservation":"","distance":"126 km","change":"2","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"13:37","starttime":"13:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5725 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"13:49","starttime":"13:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"14:00","starttime":"13:54","platform":"4","traininfo":"5504 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Eger)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"14:47","starttime":"14:45","platform":"6","traininfo":"","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"14:55","starttime":"14:53","platform":"3","traininfo":"566 RÓZSA IC (Budapest-Keleti - Budapest-Nyugati)Mutasd a térképen!","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"15:32","starttime":"15:31","platform":"9","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"1:54","starttime":"13:37","cost2nd":"3.020 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":null,"start":""},{"class_name":" 2. ","cost1st":"","destinationtime":"15:50","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"2","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"13:37","starttime":"13:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5725 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"13:49","starttime":"13:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"14:00","starttime":"13:54","platform":"4","traininfo":"5504 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Eger)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"14:47","starttime":"14:45","platform":"6","traininfo":"","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"15:00","platform":"1","traininfo":"5326 személy ( - Hidasnémeti)","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"15:50","platform":"8","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:13","starttime":"13:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 2. ","ticket":null,"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.020 Ft ","destinationtime":"16:21","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"1","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"13:37","starttime":"13:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5725 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"13:49","starttime":"13:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"14:57","starttime":"14:56","platform":"4","traininfo":"526 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Sátoraljaújhely)Mutasd a térképen!","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"16:22","starttime":"16:21","platform":"8","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:44","starttime":"13:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":null,"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.300 Ft ","destinationtime":"17:31","reservation":"","distance":"126 km","change":"2","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"15:37","starttime":"15:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5745 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"15:47","starttime":"15:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"15:54","platform":"4","traininfo":"5506 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Eger)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"16:45","platform":"6","traininfo":"","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"16:53","platform":"3","traininfo":"653 TULIPÁN IC (Budapest-Keleti - Budapest-Nyugati)","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"17:31","platform":"9","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"1:54","starttime":"15:37","cost2nd":"3.020 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":{"params":{"elvira":"http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll","via":"http://imenetrend.com","k":"","alany":"27","ref":"O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010041B00007EU00990401041B03A9242500321500020300000041B041DE900023D800321500050D0000103ED03F56D00023830030DD000A0B0000103B303BA6D00025B800313600000000000000003A969000","Lang":"HU"},"url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas","full_url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas?k=&ref=O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010041B00007EU00990401041B03A9242500321500020300000041B041DE900023D800321500050D0000103ED03F56D00023830030DD000A0B0000103B303BA6D00025B800313600000000000000003A969000&alany=27&elvira=http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll&Lang=HU&via=http://imenetrend.com"},"start":""},{"class_name":" 2. ","cost1st":"","destinationtime":"17:50","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"2","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"15:37","starttime":"15:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5745 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"15:47","starttime":"15:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"15:54","platform":"4","traininfo":"5506 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Eger)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"16:45","platform":"6","traininfo":"","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"17:00","platform":"1","traininfo":"5346 személy ( - Miskolc-Tiszai)","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"17:50","platform":"8","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:13","starttime":"15:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 2. ","ticket":{"params":{"elvira":"http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll","via":"http://imenetrend.com","k":"","alany":"27","ref":"O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010042E00007EU00990400042E03A9242500309300010900000042E03FCE900023D800309300050D0000103ED03FC6D00023830030DD000A0B0000103B303BA6D00025B800313600000000000000003A969000","Lang":"HU"},"url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas","full_url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas?k=&ref=O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010042E00007EU00990400042E03A9242500309300010900000042E03FCE900023D800309300050D0000103ED03FC6D00023830030DD000A0B0000103B303BA6D00025B800313600000000000000003A969000&alany=27&elvira=http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll&Lang=HU&via=http://imenetrend.com"},"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.020 Ft ","destinationtime":"18:21","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"1","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"15:37","starttime":"15:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5745 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"15:47","starttime":"15:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"16:56","platform":"4","traininfo":"528 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Sátoraljaújhely)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"18:21","platform":"8","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:44","starttime":"15:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":{"params":{"elvira":"http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll","via":"http://imenetrend.com","k":"","alany":"27","ref":"O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010044D00007EU00770300044D03A9242500307800050B00000044D045DE90002383003078000A0B0000103B303F86D00025B800313600000000000000003A969000","Lang":"HU"},"url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas","full_url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas?k=&ref=O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010044D00007EU00770300044D03A9242500307800050B00000044D045DE90002383003078000A0B0000103B303F86D00025B800313600000000000000003A969000&alany=27&elvira=http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll&Lang=HU&via=http://imenetrend.com"},"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.300 Ft ","destinationtime":"19:31","reservation":"","distance":"126 km","change":"2","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"17:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5723 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"17:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"17:54","platform":"4","traininfo":"5516 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Eger)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"18:45","platform":"5","traininfo":"","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"18:53","platform":"3","traininfo":"568 TOKAJ IC (Budapest-Keleti - Debrecen)","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"19:31","platform":"9","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"1:54","starttime":"17:37","cost2nd":"3.020 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":{"params":{"elvira":"http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll","via":"http://imenetrend.com","k":"","alany":"27","ref":"O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010049300007EU009904010493042124250031150002030000004930495E900023D800311500050D000010465046D6D00023830030EC000A0B00001042B04326D00025B8003124000000000000000042169000","Lang":"HU"},"url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas","full_url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas?k=&ref=O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010049300007EU009904010493042124250031150002030000004930495E900023D800311500050D000010465046D6D00023830030EC000A0B00001042B04326D00025B8003124000000000000000042169000&alany=27&elvira=http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll&Lang=HU&via=http://imenetrend.com"},"start":""},{"class_name":" 2. ","cost1st":"","destinationtime":"19:50","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"2","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"17:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5723 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"17:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"17:54","platform":"4","traininfo":"5516 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Eger)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"18:45","platform":"5","traininfo":"","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"19:00","platform":"1","traininfo":"5056 személy ( - Miskolc-Tiszai)","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"19:50","platform":"8","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:13","starttime":"17:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 2. ","ticket":{"params":{"elvira":"http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll","via":"http://imenetrend.com","k":"","alany":"27","ref":"O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A011101004A600007EU0099040004A6042124250030120001090000004A60474E900023D800301200050D00001046504746D00023830030EC000A0B00001042B04326D00025B8003124000000000000000042169000","Lang":"HU"},"url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas","full_url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas?k=&ref=O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A011101004A600007EU0099040004A6042124250030120001090000004A60474E900023D800301200050D00001046504746D00023830030EC000A0B00001042B04326D00025B8003124000000000000000042169000&alany=27&elvira=http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll&Lang=HU&via=http://imenetrend.com"},"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.020 Ft ","destinationtime":"20:21","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"1","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"17:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5723 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"17:47","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"18:56","platform":"4","traininfo":"5208 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Sátoraljaújhely)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"20:21","platform":"8","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:44","starttime":"17:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":{"params":{"elvira":"http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll","via":"http://imenetrend.com","k":"","alany":"27","ref":"O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A011101004C500007EU0077030004C50421242500305400050B0000004C504D5E90002383003054000A0B00001042B04706D00025B8003124000000000000000042169000","Lang":"HU"},"url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas","full_url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas?k=&ref=O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A011101004C500007EU0077030004C50421242500305400050B0000004C504D5E90002383003054000A0B00001042B04706D00025B8003124000000000000000042169000&alany=27&elvira=http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll&Lang=HU&via=http://imenetrend.com"},"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.300 Ft ","destinationtime":"21:31","reservation":"","distance":"126 km","change":"2","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"19:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5711 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"19:47","platform":"2","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"19:54","platform":"4","traininfo":"5508 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Eger)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"20:45","platform":"4","traininfo":"","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"20:53","platform":"3","traininfo":"508 SZINVA IC (Budapest-Keleti - Miskolc-Tiszai)","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"21:31","platform":"1","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"1:54","starttime":"19:37","cost2nd":"3.020 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":{"params":{"elvira":"http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll","via":"http://imenetrend.com","k":"","alany":"27","ref":"O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010050B00007EU00990401050B0499242500301C00020300000050B04E5E900023D800301C00050D0000104DD04E56D00023830030E1000A0B0000104A304AA6D00025B8003118000000000000000049969000","Lang":"HU"},"url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas","full_url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas?k=&ref=O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010050B00007EU00990401050B0499242500301C00020300000050B04E5E900023D800301C00050D0000104DD04E56D00023830030E1000A0B0000104A304AA6D00025B8003118000000000000000049969000&alany=27&elvira=http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll&Lang=HU&via=http://imenetrend.com"},"start":""},{"class_name":" 2. ","cost1st":"","destinationtime":"21:50","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"2","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"19:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5711 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"19:47","platform":"2","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"19:54","platform":"4","traininfo":"5508 sebes (Budapest-Keleti - Eger)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"20:45","platform":"4","traininfo":"","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"21:00","platform":"1","traininfo":"5058 személy ( - Miskolc-Tiszai)","start":"Füzesabony"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"21:50","platform":"7","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:13","starttime":"19:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 2. ","ticket":{"params":{"elvira":"http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll","via":"http://imenetrend.com","k":"","alany":"27","ref":"O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010051E00007EU00990400051E0499242500301400010900000051E04ECE900023D800301400050D0000104DD04EC6D00023830030E1000A0B0000104A304AA6D00025B8003118000000000000000049969000","Lang":"HU"},"url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas","full_url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas?k=&ref=O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010051E00007EU00990400051E0499242500301400010900000051E04ECE900023D800301400050D0000104DD04EC6D00023830030E1000A0B0000104A304AA6D00025B8003118000000000000000049969000&alany=27&elvira=http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll&Lang=HU&via=http://imenetrend.com"},"start":""},{"class_name":" 2. ","cost1st":"","destinationtime":"22:22","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"1","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"19:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5711 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"19:47","platform":"2","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"20:57","platform":"4","traininfo":"5008 gyors (Budapest-Keleti - Miskolc-Tiszai)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"22:22","platform":"9","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"2:45","starttime":"19:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 2. ","ticket":{"params":{"elvira":"http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll","via":"http://imenetrend.com","k":"","alany":"27","ref":"O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010053E00007EU00770300053E04992425002FFC00050B00000053E04E9E90002383002FFC000A0B0000104A304E96D00025B8003118000000000000000049969000","Lang":"HU"},"url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas","full_url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas?k=&ref=O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A0111010053E00007EU00770300053E04992425002FFC00050B00000053E04E9E90002383002FFC000A0B0000104A304E96D00025B8003118000000000000000049969000&alany=27&elvira=http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll&Lang=HU&via=http://imenetrend.com"},"start":""},{"class_name":" 1.2. ","cost1st":"3.020 Ft ","destinationtime":"00:21","reservation":"-","distance":"126 km","change":"1","destination":"Miskolc-Tiszai","details":[{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"22:37","platform":"","traininfo":"5741 személy (Szolnok - Hatvan)","start":"Jászfényszaru"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"22:47","platform":"","traininfo":"","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"22:56","platform":"4","traininfo":"5108 gyors (Budapest-Keleti - Miskolc-Tiszai)","start":"Hatvan"},{"starttime_real":"","starttime":"00:21","platform":"6","traininfo":"","start":"Miskolc-Tiszai"}],"totaltime":"1:44","starttime":"22:37","cost2nd":"2.480 Ft","class":" 1.2. ","ticket":{"params":{"elvira":"http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll","via":"http://imenetrend.com","k":"","alany":"27","ref":"O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A011101005B500007EU0077030005B5054D242500301D00050B0000005B50560E9000238300301D000A0B00001055705606D00025B8003133000000000000000054D69000","Lang":"HU"},"url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas","full_url":"https://jegyvasarlas.mav-start.hu/eTicketV2/Jegykivalasztas?k=&ref=O334EE0BAA525B811E200111210000005A011101005B500007EU0077030005B5054D242500301D00050B0000005B50560E9000238300301D000A0B00001055705606D00025B8003133000000000000000054D69000&alany=27&elvira=http://elvira.mav-start.hu/elvira.dll&Lang=HU&via=http://imenetrend.com"},"start":""}]}
```

This is a regular train service JSON code. I would like to insert data in an object.
Now I am getting data in the above format from a web service into Win phone 7.
But while trying to parse I am facing a error:

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(_dataString)))
            {
                //parse into jsonser
                var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyPersonClass[]));
                MyPersonClass[] obj = (MyPersonClass[])ser.ReadObject(ms);
            }
```

This is the MyPersonClass:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyPersonClass
{
    private string _Date;
    private string _Route;
    private string _Name;
    private string _Change;
    private string _Class;
    private string _Class_name;
    private string _Cost1st;
    private string _Cost2nd;
    private string _Destenation;
    private string _Destenationtime;
    private string _Platform;
    private string _Start;
    private string _Starttime;
    private string _Starttime_real;
    private string _Traininfo;
    private string _Distance;
    private string _Reservation;
    private string _Ticket;
    private string _Full_url;
    private string _Params;
    private string _lang;
    private string _Alany;
    private string _Elvira;
    private string _K;
    private string _Ref;
    private string _Via;
    private string _Url;
    private string _Totaltime;

    [DataMember(Name = "date")]
    public string _date 
    {
        get { return _Date; }
        set { _Date = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "route")]
    public string _route
    {
        get { return _Route; }
        set { _Date = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "change")]
    public string _change
    {
        get { return _Date; }
        set { _Date = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "class")]
    public string _class
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "class_name")]
    public string _class_name
    {
        get { return _Class_name; }
        set { _Class_name = value; }
    }
                 .......

    [DataMember(Name = "k")]
    public string _k
    {
        get { return _K; }
        set { _K = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "ref")]
    public string _ref
    {
        get { return _Ref; }
        set { _Ref = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "via")]
    public string _via
    {
        get { return _Via; }
        set { _Via = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "url")]
    public string _url
    {
        get { return _Url; }
        set { _Url = value; }
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "totaltime")]
    public string _totaltime
    {
        get { return _Totaltime; }
        set { _Totaltime = value; }
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you add the missing code from your `MyPerson` class?  The code you provided works for me (in LINQPad), after adding square brackets around your JSON string.  Even without the brackets, it did not throw an exception (just returned an empty array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a couple of problems here.  The first is that your `MyPersonClass` type doesn't quite match the structure of the json example that you've given.  If you take that json string and plug it into [this site](http://json2csharp.com/), it'll usually(if the json string you give it includes null values or empty arrays, it won't be able to give you accurate types for those entries) give you the classes that you need for parsing that string, and the `RootObject` class that it will give you would then be your `MyPersonClass`.

The second problem is that while the json string you gave as an example is just a single object, you're telling the DataContractJsonSerializer that you want it to deserialize an array of objects.  What you probably want is:

```
var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyPersonClass)); 
MyPersonClass obj = (MyPersonClass)ser.ReadObject(ms);
```